# Returning only one item of an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to grab one array element and update a bunch of it's properties. Here is how I am currently doing it which feels like the wrong way to me. Can this be done without having to loop through the array to match the _id? Can you select just one of the array elements by _id to be updated?

```
Schemas.Users.findOne({ _id: req.session.userID })
.select('friends').exec(function(err, user){
  if (err) return next(err);

  // figure out which friend I should be updating
  var index = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < user.friends.length; i++) {
    if (user.friends[i]._id == req.params.friendID) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  // if we didn't find the friend, something went wrong
  if (index === null) {
    console.log('Error: index not found.');
    return res.redirect('somepage');                
  }

  // update friend
  user.friends[index].name = req.body.name;

  user.markModified('friends');
  user.save();

  return res.redirect('somepage');
});
```

Comment: It depends on how your **Schema** is defined and whether you are separating the "friends" into another model or whether it is "embedded". That information is not in your question.

Comment: Sorry, friends was not in a separate model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Mongoose have an [id](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#types_documentarray_MongooseDocumentArray-id) method designed especially for your case:

```
Schemas.Users.findOne({
  _id: req.session.userID,
}).select('friends').exec(function(err, user){
  if (err) return next(err);

  var friend = user.friends.id(req.params.friendID);

  // if we didn't find the friend, something went wrong
  if (friend === null) {
    console.log('Error: index not found.');
    return res.redirect('somepage');                
  }

  // update friend
  friend.name = req.body.name;

  user.save();

  return res.redirect('somepage');
});
```

If your only goal it to set the name of the user's friend, then you may consider using [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) instead of `findOne` and `save`:

```
Schemas.Users.update({
  _id: req.session.userID,
  friends: {$elemMatch: {
    _id: req.params.friendID
  }}
}, {
  'friends.$.name': req.params.friendID
}).exec(function(err, numberAffected){
  if (err) return next(err);

  // if we didn't find the friend, something went wrong
  if (numberAffected === 0) {
    console.log('Error: index not found.');
    return res.redirect('somepage');                
  }

  return res.redirect('somepage');
});
```

`Update` is faster, but Mongoose `setters`, `validators` and `middlewares` don't work with it.

Comment: Using the top method seems to be the best, but when it saves it wipes out the rest of the array, leaving only the one I was updating. I am updating about 20 things in that array, so update is probably not the best option here.

Comment: I don't think it likes the idea of selecting only one from the array, and then saving - loses all other array elements.

Comment: @codephobia Yes, I missed it. Updated ny answer with better approach.

Comment: Should that be user.friends.id(req.params.friendID)?

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Sorry :)

Comment: Sorry, still not working. Getting an error `has no method 'id'`.

Comment: Nevermind, I still had update instead of findOne. It is working perfectly now. Marking yours as correct answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's strange, I just checked it in my REPL. Which version of `Mongoose` are you using?